# Only play the animated gifs that are visible in the browser window

Tags: performance, gif, animated-gif

I want to create an infinite scroll website that will present a massive amount of animated GIFs. The problem is, having all of the GIFs animating continuously after page load is causing severe performance issues, so that the website running very slow.

Is there a javascript-snippet or plugin, that stops all GIFs that are not visible in the browser window?

A solution is [freezeframe.js](http://freezeframe.chrisantonellis.com/), but it forces the user to click or hover the animations.

Comment: Check the freezeframe documentation, there is a paragraph "run with infinite scroll"

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. Thank you!!!